# Can't get :onclick to work in rails3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, onclick

I'm trying to simply change the menu tab color after someone clicks on it, but am having trouble getting rails to recognize javascript.  I've searched around and tested and found that :onclick isn't even registering.  In the below snippet, I'm not even getting the "made it here" in my firebug console.  I've included the javascript file with the one function

```
function updateMenuTab(current_id) {...}
```

Any thoughts?  Thank you in advance.

```
   <%= javascript_include_tag "menuTab" %>

   <td id="tab-about" onmouseover="updateMenuTab('tab-about')">
          <%= link_to("About", :url => {:controller => "about", :action => "solarcloud"}, :onlick => "console.log('made it here'); updateMenuTab('tab-about');") %>
  </td>
```

Comment: In the snippet you provided, it is spelled :onlick. Is that a typo? Just checking.

Comment: Registering an `onmouseover` event for the parent and a `onclick` event for the child which seem to do the same (?) might  be causing you some problems as well. But if your `onmouseover` event works, I'd as well wonder about that typo in your snippet.

Comment: A little fun: `my_dog.onlick = function(e) { if(e.target == self) { self.say("stop licking me!"); } };`

Comment: @Jacob that is called when my_dog is licked…

Comment: @Time Machine, Well, it could also be called when the dog licks something too...

Answer (score 0):

Well rails 3 is mainly about unobtrusive javascript. [You can read the advantages here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)
I would suggest to do like this if you are using jquery:

```
$("#tab-about").mouseover(updateMenuTab('tab-about'));
```

or for click:

```
$("#tab-about").click(updateMenuTab('tab-about'));
```